# Jquery Prev() last 3 tag names to get data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey all I am trying to figure out the path of which it takes for me to go from a button click on the **ADDtab_138269500** and go **back** *(previous)* all the way to the **span** tag it gets to first going backwords.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/w0jtvyab/3/) for you to see

The JS code I have thus far that doesn't seem to be it (as it doesn't have data for that tag):

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $('[data-item-id="ADDtab_138269500"]').click(function() {
    var blah = $(this).prev().prev().closest("div").find('span');

    console.log(blah);
  });
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="input-group" style="margin-top: 40px;">
  <span data-id="Writter Status" style="color: rgb(255, 46, 49); position: absolute; z-index: 8; text-transform: uppercase; text-shadow: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.87) 0px 1px 1px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; left: 13px; top: 14px; width: 300px; letter-spacing: 1px;">Writter Status</span>
  <span id="lblBG" style="box-shadow: 0px 5px 6px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);border-radius: 4px; border: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 1); border-image: none; left: 7px; top: 14px; width: 98px; height: 16px; position: absolute; z-index: 3; background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 1);"></span>
    <div class="input-group-addon" style="width: 33px;">
      <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWw..." id="iconImg_currentUsers" style="width: 20px; height:20px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <span id="inventory" class="tips form-control input-sm" data_tooltip="example 1" style="width: 500px; background-color: rgb(254, 231, 231); height: 37px;" data-cnt="0"><div class="select3-multiple-input-container">
      <span class="select3-multiple-selected-item" data-item-id="1" style="padding-right: 5px;">Pending</span>
      <span class="select3-multiple-selected-item" data-item-id="2" style="padding-right: 5px;">Approved</span>
      <span class="select3-multiple-selected-item" data-item-id="3" style="padding-right: 5px;">Denied</span>
      <span class="select3-multiple-selected-item" data-item-id="ADDtab_138269500" style="padding-right: 5px; background-color: rgb(40, 177, 40); z-index: 50;" data-popmodal_id="185">ADD ITEM</span>
        <div style="top: 23px; left: 168.344px;" data-popmodal_id="185" data-popmodal="open" class="popModal animated bottomLeft fadeInBottom">
        </div>
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" class="select3-multiple-input" placeholder="" style="width: 678px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="select3-multiple-input select3-width-detector"></span>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    </span>
</div>
</div>
<div id=""></div>
```

What I am looking to achieve is getting the value of **data-id="Writter Status"** from the top **span tag**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method to achieve this would be to go up the DOM from the button to the nearest parent container of both elements, then `find()` the `span` you want to read the `data-id` from, like this:

```js
$('[data-item-id="ADDtab_138269500"]').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).closest("div.input-group").find('span[data-id]').data('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

```css
.input-group {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.input-group .status {
  color: rgb(255, 46, 49);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.87) 0px 1px 1px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  left: 13px;
  top: 14px;
  width: 300px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.input-group .input-group-addon {
  width: 33px;
}

.input-group .input-group-addon img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.input-group .select3-multiple-selected-item {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.input-group .select3-multiple-selected-item.highlight {
  background-color: rgb(40, 177, 40);
  z-index: 50;
}

.input-group .popModal {
  top: 23px;
  left: 168.344px;
}

.input-group .select3-multiple-input {
  width: 678px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

#lblBG {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 6px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
  border-image: none;
  left: 7px;
  top: 14px;
  width: 98px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 1);
}

#inventory {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(254, 231, 231);
  height: 37px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <span data-id="Writter Status" class="status">Writter Status</span>
  <span id="lblBG"></span>
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWw..." id="iconImg_currentUsers">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <span id="inventory" class="tips form-control input-sm" data_tooltip="example 1" data-cnt="0">
      <div class="select3-multiple-input-container">
        <span class="select3-multiple-selected-item" data-item-id="1">Pending</span>
        <span class="select3-multiple-selected-item" data-item-id="2">Approved</span>
        <span class="select3-multiple-selected-item" data-item-id="3">Denied</span>
        <span class="select3-multiple-selected-item highlight" data-item-id="ADDtab_138269500" data-popmodal_id="185">ADD ITEM</span>
        <div data-popmodal_id="185" data-popmodal="open" class="popModal animated bottomLeft fadeInBottom"></div>
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" class="select3-multiple-input" placeholder="" />
        <span class="select3-multiple-input select3-width-detector"></span>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, you really should not be using inline styling where possible. Extract your CSS rules to an external stylesheet as in the example above. Note how much cleaner the HTML is to read and understand.

Finally, your HTML is currently invalid as `div` elements cannot be children of `span` elements.

Comment: Yep that did it Rory. Thanks for the solution and suggestions! :)